# Search XML file from within Wordpress?

Tags: embed, xml

We use [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) internally for an defect mgmt system.
We want to provide defect tracking to our clients.

We cannot expose Jira to the web, but we do have our main site hosted on WP 3.2.1
I can export a XML file from Jira of the defects and plonk this under our Wordpress site.

I was thinking that I could come up with a basic page within Wordpress to allow our users to filter this XML list down.  i.e. Search on a reference number of keywords from the title or description nodes.

I was hoping to spot a good Jira/WP plugin but no luck.

The answer I am looking for, is:
- Is this achievable through WP
- What would be the best approach to go about this?
- Any links to similar attempts would be also beneficial.

Let me know if u need more info via the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure it need to be wordpress specific but rather you could look for a general PHP solution and make that into a page template.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PHP library which uses SOAP calls to access JIRA: https://github.com/jrbeeman/php-jira

However, if you can get the XML file into a place PHP can access it then you can use general PHP calls to parse and read the XML file, e.g. SimpleXML http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

From there you can put your code in a theme template or a plugin. Nothing Wordpress specific needs to be done to gain access to the JIRA export, your wordpress code would merely be UI over the top.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this question is platform-agnostic, as it involves creating a search interface for a given file/script/etc.

However, to implement in WordPress, you mainly need to know [how to create a Custom Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).

Then, within the body of your Custom Page Template, you add whatever code you come up with to interface with JIRA/search your XML file.

Comment: Fair point.  I was unsure on if this belonged in WP-SE or a different site, but either way, the answers given have given me a very good start.